# Can i separate a server into two different environments

Tags: linux

I want to setup magento enterprise edition for my site for that i want to go for two environments like one is development& testing environment and another one is live site. But i have only one server hosting with rackspace. Is there any possibility to separate two different environments even i change something in testing that should not affect live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Magento to make sure. However, since it runs on Apache and MySQL, you could probably do a second installation to a different Apache site (or even different httpd instance) and use a second MySQL database.

Or you could install your test instance on a home machine, if you're the only one who will be doing testing.

Comment: This should work.  Just install prod instance to the prod documentroot directory and the test instance to the test documentroot (create separate virtual hosts) and then use two different dB's.  Now if Magento includes it's own apache/mysql bundle, just install to different locations and use different ports.

Comment: yeah i already made separate subdomain for testing purpose but i dont know how to create two different instances on apache?

Comment: actually i and my client wants to test and some time my testers need to test. so it should be in the live server but without causing problem

Answer (score 0):

Host your development environment in a virtual machine on the same server. That way, you can allocate specific resource limits to the virtual machine and changes won't impact the live site as it's a completely separate instance. VMWare server and Virtualbox are free solutions to do this.

Comment: That can be a lot of overhead, so it may not be a good solution. Instead of running 2 databases in one MySQL instance, you're now running a whole second machine with its own background processes and a second MySQL instance - not to mention the additional diskspace. Also, he says he has a hosted server - that machine may already be a VM guest; if so, getting nested VMs to work will be unsupported at best, and potentially impossible.

Comment: I think better my client may need to get separate instance for testing alone. Ok thanks guys. I will try your ideas

Comment: Fair comment mfinni, especially the nested VM situation which I had not considered.